# Exchange Online: Sort conversations by time of last message

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, outlook-web-access

I am accessing Office 365 via a browser.  I would like my email conversations to be sorted by the time of the last message in each conversation.  This currently happens for most of the conversations, but not if the last message is sent by me.  Is there a way to ensure that it *always* happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When displaying Outlook mail list in the form of a conversation, Outlook seems to only use the time of the latest mail in this conversation within the current folder as the latest time of the conversation. However, for those conversations whose last message is sent by you, the latest email message is in your Sent items folder. So, the simplest workaround is that you could try to create an Outlook rule to move a copy of your sent emails to the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for that, Jeff.